# changing the name of many files by increasing the number

Tags: bash, file-rename

I want to change the file names from a terminal. I have many files, so I cannot change all of them one by one.

```
a20170606_1257.txt -> a20170606_1300.txt
a20170606_1258.txt -> a20170606_1301.txt
```

I am only able to change it by:

```
rename 57.txt 00.txt *57.txt
```

but it is not enough.

Comment: meaning `1257` to be `1300` and `1258` to be `1301`?

Comment: Yes, I want to change it in that way.

Comment: you want to change the name or increase the value of number

Comment: I want to change a name by increasing the number.

Comment: I edited your title,with  adding `increasing the number` in place of `adding 1`

Comment: Ok, thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just playing with parameter expansion to extract the longest and shortest strings of type `${str##*}` and `${str%%*}`

```
offset=43
for file in *.txt; do 
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    woe="${file%%.*}"; ext="${file##*.}"
    num="${woe##*_}"
    echo "$file" "${woe%%_*}_$((num+offset)).${ext}"
done
```

Once you have it working, remove the `echo` line and replace it with `mv -v`. Change the `offset` variable as you wish, depending on where you want to start your re-named files from.

Answer (score 1):

Perl `e` flag to rescue

```
rename -n -v  's/(?<=_)(\d+)/$1+43/e' *.txt
```

**test**

```
 dir $  ls | cat -n
     1  a20170606_1257.txt
     2  a20170606_1258.txt
 dir $  
 dir $  
 dir $  rename -n -v  's/(?<=_)(\d+)/$1+43/e' *.txt
rename(a20170606_1257.txt, a20170606_1300.txt)
rename(a20170606_1258.txt, a20170606_1301.txt)
 dir $  
 dir $  rename -v  's/(?<=_)(\d+)/$1+43/e' *.txt
a20170606_1257.txt renamed as a20170606_1300.txt
a20170606_1258.txt renamed as a20170606_1301.txt
 dir $  
 dir $  ls | cat -n
     1  a20170606_1300.txt
     2  a20170606_1301.txt
 dir $
```

---

[image: rename_with_e_flag]

---

```
rename --help:  
Usage:
    rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -e|-E *perlexpr*]*|*perlexpr*
    [ *files* ]

Options:
    -v, -verbose
            Verbose: print names of files successfully renamed.

    -n, -nono
            No action: print names of files to be renamed, but don't rename.

    -f, -force
            Over write: allow existing files to be over-written.

    -h, -help
            Help: print SYNOPSIS and OPTIONS.

    -m, -man
            Manual: print manual page.

    -V, -version
            Version: show version number.

    -e      Expression: code to act on files name.

            May be repeated to build up code (like "perl -e"). If no -e, the
            first argument is used as code.

    -E      Statement: code to act on files name, as -e but terminated by
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I received rename: invalid option -- 'n'.

Comment: try `rename --help` and see if it has `-n` option, It should have it.

Comment: I only have v,s,h,V.

Comment: Also `-n` is just for test, in fact you no need to use it. It means `print names of files to be renamed, but don't rename`

Comment: Yes, but without n I received: rename: not enough arguments

Comment: I never got this error. May you use an old version. Update you **Perl**, and your **Bash**. I always use it